# dynamic start_urls in scrapy

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl multiple pages on a site.
The variable `start_urls` is used to define pages to be crawled. 
I would initially start with 1st page, thus defining `start_urls = [1st page]` in the file `example_spider.py`

Upon getting more info from 1st page, I would determine what are next pages to be crawled, then would assign `start_urls` accordingly. Hence, I have to overwrite above example_spider.py with changes to `start_urls = [1st page, 2nd page, ..., Kth page]`, then run scrapy crawl again.

Is that the best approach or is there a better way to dynamically assign `start_urls` using scrapy API without having to overwrite `example_splider.py`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`start_urls` class attribute contains start urls - nothing more. If you have extracted urls of other pages you want to scrape - yield from `parse` callback corresponding requests with [another] callback:

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):

    name = 'my_spider'
    start_urls = [
                'http://www.domain.com/'
    ]
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        '''Parse main page and extract categories links.'''
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        urls = hxs.select("//*[@id='tSubmenuContent']/a[position()>1]/@href").extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url)
            self.log('Found category url: %s' % url)
            yield Request(url, callback = self.parseCategory)

    def parseCategory(self, response):
        '''Parse category page and extract links of the items.'''
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select("//*[@id='_list']//td[@class='tListDesc']/a/@href").extract()
        for link in links:
            itemLink = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link)
            self.log('Found item link: %s' % itemLink, log.DEBUG)
            yield Request(itemLink, callback = self.parseItem)

    def parseItem(self, response):
        ...
```

If you still want to customize start requests creation, override method [BaseSpider.start_requests()](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests)

Comment: is the parseItem(self,response) return the item?

Comment: `parseItem` as any other callback can return an `Item` or another `Request` with another callback

Comment: I got Request is not defined, help please

Comment: @WilliamKinaan [`from scrapy.http import Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects)

Comment: please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170777/scrapy-scrap-on-all-pages-that-have-this-syntext