# How to generate the start_urls dynamically in crawling?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am crawling a site which may contain a lot of `start_urls`, like:

```
http://www.a.com/list_1_2_3.htm
```

I want to populate `start_urls` like `[list_\d+_\d+_\d+\.htm]`,
and extract items from URLs like `[node_\d+\.htm]` during crawling.

Can I use `CrawlSpider` to realize this function?
And how can I generate the `start_urls` dynamically in crawling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8798235/

Comment: More info on start_requests http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

Answer (score 46):

The best way to generate URLs dynamically is to override the [start_requests](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method of the spider:

> ```
> from scrapy.http.request import Request
>
> def start_requests(self):
>       with open('urls.txt', 'rb') as urls:
>           for url in urls:
>               yield Request(url, self.parse)
> ```

Answer (score 16):

There are two questions:

1)yes you can realize this functionality by using Rules e.g ,

```
rules =(Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('node_\d+.htm')) ,callback = 'parse'))
```

[suggested reading](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html)

2) yes you can generate start_urls dynamically ,  start_urls is a

> list

e.g `>>> start_urls = ['http://www.a.com/%d_%d_%d' %(n,n+1,n+2) for n in range(0, 26)]`

```
>>> start_urls

['http://www.a.com/0_1_2', 'http://www.a.com/1_2_3', 'http://www.a.com/2_3_4', 'http://www.a.com/3_4_5', 'http://www.a.com/4_5_6', 'http://www.a.com/5_6_7',  'http://www.a.com/6_7_8', 'http://www.a.com/7_8_9', 'http://www.a.com/8_9_10','http://www.a.com/9_10_11', 'http://www.a.com/10_11_12', 'http://www.a.com/11_12_13', 'http://www.a.com/12_13_14', 'http://www.a.com/13_14_15', 'http://www.a.com/14_15_16', 'http://www.a.com/15_16_17', 'http://www.a.com/16_17_18', 'http://www.a.com/17_18_19', 'http://www.a.com/18_19_20', 'http://www.a.com/19_20_21', 'http://www.a.com/20_21_22', 'http://www.a.com/21_22_23', 'http://www.a.com/22_23_24', 'http://www.a.com/23_24_25', 'http://www.a.com/24_25_26', 'http://www.a.com/25_26_27']
```

Comment: Thank you for answers. But I want generate the start_urls during crawling: when I meet a url like 'http://www.a.com/%d_%d_%d', I add it into start_urls. I can not confirm the range of start_urls at first...

Comment: as for as i know, scrapy add start_urls Requests in scheduler at the start of crawling if you add any url in the list of start_urls during crawling that will not be executed.

Comment: For some reason (2) only works in the interpreter shell and fails in the `runspider`.

Comment: How does python know its suppose to be %d. What if you use %h or %x? Why %d?