# the order of Scrapy Crawling URLs with long start_urls list and urls yiels from spider

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Help! Reading the source code of `Scrapy` is not easy for me.
I have a very long `start_urls` list. it is about 3,000,000 in a file. So,I make the `start_urls` like this:

```
start_urls = read_urls_from_file(u"XXXX")
def read_urls_from_file(file_path):
    with codecs.open(file_path, u"r", encoding=u"GB18030") as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                url = line.strip()
                yield url
            except:
                print u"read line:%s from file failed!" % line
                continue
    print u"file read finish!"
```

MeanWhile, my spider's callback functions are like this：

```
  def parse(self, response):
        self.log("Visited %s" % response.url)
        return  Request(url=("http://www.baidu.com"), callback=self.just_test1)
    def just_test1(self, response):
        self.log("Visited %s" % response.url)
        return Request(url=("http://www.163.com"), callback=self.just_test2)
    def just_test2(self, response):
        self.log("Visited %s" % response.url)
        return []
```

my questions are:

1. the order of the urls used by downloader? Will the requests made by
   `just_test1`,`just_test2`  be used by downloader only after the all
   `start_urls` are used?(I have made some tests, it seems that the
   answer is No)
2. What decides the order? Why and How is this order? How can we control it?
3. Is this a good way to deal with so many urls which are already in a file? What else?

Thank you very much!!!

Thanks for answers.But I am still a bit confused:
[By default, Scrapy uses a LIFO queue for storing pending requests.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breath-first-or-depth-first-order)

1. The `requests` made by spiders' callback function will be given to the
   `scheduler`.Who does the same thing to `start_url's requests`?The spider
   `start_requests()` function only generate an iterator without giving
   the real requests.
2. Will the all `requests`(start_url's and callback's) be in the same request's queue?How many queues are there in `Scrapy`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, please see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566322/scrapy-crawl-urls-in-order) - I think you'll find all the answers there.

> the order of the urls used by downloader? Will the requests made by
>   just_test1,just_test2 be used by downloader only after the all
>   start_urls are used?(I have made some tests, it seems that the answer
>   is No)

You are right, the answer is `No`. The behavior is completely asynchronous: when the spider starts, `start_requests` method is called ([source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spider.py#L49)):

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
    return Request(url, dont_filter=True)
```

> What decides the order? Why and How is this order? How can we control
>   it?

By default, there is no pre-defined order - you cannot know when `Requests` from `make_requests_from_url` will arrive - it's asynchronous.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6593427/771848) on how you may control the order.
Long story short, you can override `start_requests` and mark yielded `Requests` with `priority` key (like `yield Request(url, meta={'priority': 0})`). For example, the value of `priority` can be the line number where the url was found.

> Is this a good way to deal with so many urls which are already in a
>   file? What else?

I think you should read your file and yield urls directly in `start_requests` method: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10379463/771848).

So, you should do smth like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    with codecs.open(self.file_path, u"r", encoding=u"GB18030") as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            try:
                url = line.strip()
                yield Request(url, meta={'priority': index})
            except:
                continue
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!I am still a bit confused.[By default, Scrapy uses a LIFO queue for storing pending requests.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breath-first-or-depth-first-order).

Comment: I've complemented my problem.It's too long for comments.The hope can obtain your answer.thank you so much!