# scrapy scrape on all pages that have this syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to scrapy on all pages that have this syntaxt

```
mywebsite/?page=INTEGER
```

I tried this:

```
start_urls = ['MyWebsite']
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/\?page=\d+']), 'parse')]
```

but it seems that the link still `MyWebsite`. so please what should I do to make it understand that i want to add `/?page=NumberOfPage` ? please?

#### edit

i mean that i want to __scrape__ these pages:

```
mywebsite/?page=1
mywebsite/?page=2
mywebsite/?page=3
mywebsite/?page=4
mywebsite/?page=5
..
..
..
mywebsite/?page=7677654
```

#### my code

```
start_urls = [
        'http://example.com/?page=%s' % page for page in xrange(1,100000)
    ]
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('my xpath')
    for site in sites:
         
        DateDifference= site.xpath('xpath for date difference').extract()[0]
         
        if DateDifference.days < 8:
            yield Request(Link, meta={'date': Date}, callback = self.crawl)
```

I want to get all the data of pages that have been added in the last 7 days. I don't know how many pages have been added in the last 7 days. so i think that i can crawl on a larg number of pages , lets say 100000, then i check the `datedifference` if it is less that 7 days i want to `yield`  if not i want to stop crawling at all.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are using an URL instead of `MyWebsite` in `start_urls`? Are you using `CrawlSpider`? Are you using [`allowed_domains`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.allowed_domains) attribute? Please describe better what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @warwaruk yes i am using all of that . please check the edited question

Comment: See also this: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/47
If you have too many pages, it might eat a lot of memory. So you should do this in chunks.

Comment: could you share your spider code and console log? (replace your domain with "example.com" if you want) You can use a gist at github or pastebin

Comment: @pault. i justed edited the question, plesae check

Comment: @pault. i don't know if this is the correct approach for doing my purpose. if not please advice me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to crawl all pages that are younger than 7 days.
One way to do it is to follow each page in order (assuming page n°1 is the youngest, n°2 is older than n°1, n°3 older than n°2...).

You can do something like

```
start_urls = ['mywebsite/?page=1']

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    DateDifference= sel.xpath('xpath for date difference').extract()[0]

    i = response.meta['index'] if 'index' in response.meta else 1

    if DateDifference.days < 8:
        yield Request(Link, meta={'date': Date}, callback = self.crawl)
        i += 1
        yield Request('mywebsite/?page='+str(i), meta={'index':i}, callback=self.parse)
```

The idea is to execute `parse` sequentially. If this is the first time you enter the function, `response.meta['index']` isn't defined: the index is 1. If this is a call after we already parsed another page, `response.meta['index']` is defined: the index indicates the number of the page currently scraped.

Comment: it seems that i++ makes exception

Comment: why you are checking [index] please?

Comment: Yep, not pythonic :) Edited answer, you get the idea

Comment: i got your idea. i just don't know why u r checking [index]

Comment: Is this clearer? The `index` is the way to know where we are in the sequential crawling of the numerous pages.

Comment: I got this exception ` local variable 'i' referenced before assignment`

Comment: it seems that the exception onf `index` is because the first time, there is not index meta data right? how can i solve it please?

Comment: Yep, once again this wasn't the pythonic way to check whether a dict key exists. This should be better.

Comment: every thing is going correct exception that i can't do `page+i` because one of type str and one of type int. can you help please?

Comment: i found the solution, i just need to do this str(i)

Comment: you are great, i appreciate your help. you the one buddy

Comment: question please :), do you scrap the first page twice ?

Comment: Also please, make i += 1 the fist statement in the `if` condition to avoid scraping the fist page twich

Comment: Nope, this shouldn't scrap the first page more than once. First `parse` call: `index` is 1, we increment, request `mywebsite/?2`, index is 2, etc... You can move up `i += 1` but the first yield doesn't use it so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

`CrawlSpider` with rules will not help in this cases. Rules are used to extract links from the first page which match your patterns. Obviously your start url page doesn't have links to all those pages, that's why you don't get them.

Something like this should work:

```
class MyWebsiteSpider(Spider):
    ...

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in xrange(7677654):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url('mywebsite/?page=%d' % i)
```

Comment: If you want to use a loop. I could do that like this: `start_urls = [
        'mywebsite/?page=%s' % page for page in xrange(1,5)]` . However, do u think that it is mandatory to set the rang ? i mean isn't there any way to not specifiy the rang and then later on on the code i can stop crawling if a condition happened?

Comment: please in your answer, i don't need to specifiy the start_urls?

Comment: The [default implementation](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spider.py#L48) uses `start_urls`. I've overridden it, so `start_urls` is not needed. Having the source you can see how spider works and what is the better apporach.

Comment: You are asking if you need to use a `range`. It depends on your task. You need to get URLs to those pages from somewhere. You can either find the URLs on the start page or generate them by yourself if you know the pattern.